# How to import wordpress blogs to hubspot which is in xml format using php

Tags: php, wordpress, import, hubspot

I have a XML file which contains wordpress blog posts. I needed to import it into Hubspot. I tried importing using Blog Importer in Hubspot. But it returns error. Please help me in importing the wordpress blogs to hubspot using api.
Thank You